# How to carry value in every request selected on first request in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing an application in which on first page select city after this on every request data will come for only for selected city. How can we persist this without authentication or I have to pass this in URL every time. 
I am using spring boot and Thymeleaf.

Comment: @AliDehghani What happen when cookies are disabled.

Comment: Can't use it...Maybe use local storage..

Answer (score 1):

You have various options.

1. The first and obvious is to pass the city on every request as you point. But this can be painful.
2. A second option is to store this value in session so you can get this value every time you need it. But be careful handling it, do not forget to update it when its necesary etc.

with Spring MVC you can store data in session in your controller doing this:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
Session session = attr.getRequest().getSession();    
session.setAttribute("city", cityName);
```

To recover data from session

```
session.getAttribute("city");
```

Even if you do not use SpringMVC you can get the session from HttpRequest, is much more standard, but only avaliable when you have access to HttpRequest object:

```
Session session = request.getSession();    
session.setAttribute("city", cityName);
```

Comment: Villa is session available for non authenticated user and user select city only once I dont want to choose again and again. Is there any annotation or configuration available?.

Comment: recover data from session should be session.geetAttribute("city"); insted of session.setAttribute("city");  am I right?.

Comment: Session is created for the first request even forn non authenticated users. And yes it is getAttribute(), i made a typo. Answer updated

Comment: correct but I think using @SessionAttributes is much easier.

Comment: There is another easier option avaliable even if you do not use Spring MVC: get the session from HTTPRequest, for example request.getSession(); Java API info http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29

Comment: Not easier but standard, but this question about spring MVC check tags, if he is not using it already we are not going to give these answers 

Answer (score 1):

you can use session to store it, in spring MVC there is `@SessionAttributes` you can use it inside your controller, here am expecting that you are use "city" as name for your attribute.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("city")
public class EditCityForm {
    // ...
}
```